# Extending WC_Cart in woocommerce

Tags: plugins, customization

I am trying to extend WC_Cart in woocommerce, from what i understand my code should be correct. However when I load the cart I get the following message.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method WC_Cart::get_prediscount_total() in ...
```

Code in my plugin:

```
class My_WC_Cart extends WC_Cart { 
    public function get_prediscount_total() {
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_total', woocommerce_price( $this->total * 5 ) ); 
    } 
}
```

The output code is

```
 echo $woocommerce->cart->get_prediscount_total();
```

This works when the codes in `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/class-wc-cart.php` but the moment I try to extend it it fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending WooCommerce cart class is a bit tricky, but possible.

Lets assume you have a plugin and a file `class-my-wc-cart.php` with extended cart class inside. Then in the main plugin file you need to do following:

```
// load your My_WC_Cart class
require_once 'class-my-wc-cart.php';

// setup woocommerce to use your cart class    
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'wpse8170_woocommerce_init' );
function wpse8170_woocommerce_init() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( !is_admin() || defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        $woocommerce->cart = new My_WC_Cart();
    }
}

// override empty cart function to use your cart class
if ( !function_exists( 'woocommerce_empty_cart' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_empty_cart() {
        global $woocommerce;

        if ( ! isset( $woocommerce->cart ) || $woocommerce->cart == '' ) {
            $woocommerce->cart = new My_WC_Cart();
            $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart( false );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene. I would have never figured that out on my own, and its an approach that I thought of but couldn't find any documentation to help with. Thank you so much, that helped more than you could ever know.

Comment: You are missing `{` brace on your `if` statement of the `woocommerce_empty_cart` function

Comment: And if I want to override WC_Shortcode_Cart? I added an Address field (I wrote a custom shipping method to limit shipping by streets and house numbers) overriding cart/calculate-shipping.php template file, and now I need to edit the calculation code that is in such class.